# Use Linq to remove dulicates that vary by one column value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list, ApplesList

```
AppleId    Color
----------------
1          Green
1          Red
2          Red
3          Green
4          Red
4          Green
```

And would like to combine the list like so:

```
AppleId    Green   Red
------------------------
1           1       1
2           0       1
3           1       0
4           1       1
```

The duplicate AppleId records have been removed and the Color column has been split into two Boolean columns. How would this be done in Linq?

**Edit** 
What if I had another value I wanted to keep from the first list? So the first table would now be like this:

```
AppleId    Color     Value
-----------------------------
1          Green       Value1
1          Red         Value1
2          Red         Value2
3          Green       Value3
4          Red         Value4
4          Green       Value4
```

and the grouped table would be like this:

```
AppleId    Green   Red     Value
-----------------------------------
1           1       1       Value1
2           0       1       Value2
3           1       0       Value3
4           1       1       Value4
```

I tried using

```
var q = items.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
             .Select(group => new 
                     {
                         Id = group.Key, 
                         Green = group.Any(item => item.Color == "Green"), 
                         Red = group.Any(item => item.Color == "Red"),
                         Value = x.Value
                     });
```

and some other variations, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: What is the actual data structure you are using?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Have you got this as a SQL query?

Comment: I tried to create two separate lists and then join them, but I didn't get very far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using linq group by:

```
var items = new List<Item>
{
    new Item {Color = "Green", Id = 1},
    new Item {Color = "Red", Id = 1},
    new Item {Color = "Red", Id = 2},
    new Item {Color = "Green", Id = 3},
    new Item {Color = "Red", Id = 4},
    new Item {Color = "Green", Id = 4},
};

var q = items.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
             .Select(group => new 
                     {
                         Id = group.Key, 
                         Green = group.Any(item => item.Color == "Green"), 
                         Red = group.Any(item => item.Color == "Red") 
                     });
```

Comment: I think OP wants the counts, not a boolean "Any".

Comment: From question: Color column has been split into two Boolean columns.

Comment: Yeah you're right. +1 then, not sure why you got downvoted.